# onLongclick, text view should increase its value by 1 after every one minute

Tags: java, android, timer

`onLongClick` or `onLongLouch` a `TextView` , I need to increase its value by 1 every 60 seconds, like this:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="00 min"
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    />
```

Comment: yeah, so what is the error??

Comment: i don't know how to increase text by 1 every minute

Answer (score 0):

Create a Timer that runs each time in miliseconds.

```
 final Handler handlerIncrementar = new Handler();
Timer timerTexto = new Timer();
TimerTask tareaEjecucion = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handlerIncrementar.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    yourtextview.setTextSize(yourtextview.getTextSize() + 1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
timerTexto.schedule(tareaEjecucion, 0, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Code will increase the counter by one every one secound till you hold the touch on text view and stops when you relese the touch

```
private TimerTask timerTask;
private TextView textView;
private int counter = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int code = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    if (code == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        startTimer();
    } else if ((code == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) || (code == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) || (code == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)) {
        stoptimertask();
    }
    return true;
}

public void stoptimertask() {
    //stop the timer, if it's not already null
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}

Timer timer = new Timer();

public void startTimer() {
    //set a new Timer
    timer = new Timer();

    //initialize the TimerTask's job
    initializeTimerTask();

    //schedule the timer, to wake up every 1 second
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000); //
}


public void initializeTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(counter++ + " Sec");
                }
            });


        }
    };
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: unable to override onTOuch

Comment: you have to implements **View.OnTouchListener** in your activity

Like 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener